How to search from dataset with multiple statements
How to search data from dataset with multiple statements or criteria. So far, this is my current code. Basically what I want to happen is, I want to search data even some controls(e.g textbox, combobox is null).
example1: (between date1 and date2) and check_corporate = "something"
example2: (check_group="something") and (check_name Like '%" & txt_searchReports.Text & "%') and check_corporate="something"
Sub loadReports()
    da = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("select * from tblchecklist where check_group ='" & combo_groupReports.Text & "' order by check_date asc", conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "tblchecklist")
    dgv_reports.DataSource = (ds.Tables("tblchecklist"))
End Sub

Sub searchReports()
    Dim date1 As String = dateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim date2 As String = dateTo.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    da = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("select * from tblchecklist  WHERE (check_date between '" & date1 & "' and '" & date2 & "')" _
                                                       & "and (check_corporate = '" & combo_corpReports.Text & "'" _
                                                       & "and check_group = '" & combo_groupReports.Text & "'" _
                                                       & "and check_name Like '%" & txt_searchReports.Text & "%' or check_num like '%" & txt_searchReports.Text & "%')", conn)


    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "tblchecklist")
    dgv_reports.DataSource = (ds.Tables("tblchecklist"))
End Sub

Private Sub txt_searchReports_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_searchReports.TextChanged
    searchReports()
End Sub


any alternative code is greatly appreciated also

Don't use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code. ALWAYS use parameters. There are plenty of explanations of why and how to do that. Here is mine.

If you want to use a single SQL statement with nullable parameters then the trick is to use two conditions per parameter, e.g.
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (@Columnn1 IS NULL OR Column1 = @Column1)"
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString)

With adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters
    .Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(TextBox1.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), TextBox1.Text)
    'etc
End With

If the TextBox is empty then the parameter is NULL and every record matches, as though there was no parameter, otherwise the supplied text is used as a filter. You can AND together as many such pairs of criteria as you like.
I have used SqlClient for SQL Server there but the principle is the same no matter the database or provider. Some of the details will change, e.g. MySqlDataAdapter and MySqlDbType, but the pattern won't change. Some databases and providers don't properly support named parameters, e.g. Access, so you can't use the same parameter twice in the SQL code, so you have to add two parameters per value. MySQL should have no issues though.

Would you mind sharing a sample of using parameters between two dates.

@NnekLecxe, there's no reason that you should need an example of that because the logic is exactly the same. As I have already said, use each parameter twice, with the first comparing the parameter to NULL and the second comparing the column to the parameter as normal, e.g. WHERE (@StartDate IS NULL OR DateColumn >= @StartDate) AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR DateColumn <= @EndDate). As you can see, it's exactly as I already explained, with multiple pairs of criteria ANDed together.

tried to revise my code here Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from tblchecklist where check_date between '" & date1 & "' and '" & date2 & "' and check_corporate IS NULL or check_corporate=@check_corporate", conn)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@check_corporate", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 155).Value = If(combo_corpReports.SelectedIndex = -1, CObj(DBNull.Value), combo_corpReports.Text)

With the current code, it seems to display records only with check_corporate criteria, it doesnt display data "where date between and check_corporate..." criteria. What I want to display records is that, for example if combo_corpReports selectedindex=-1, and check_groupReports = "something"... Then displayed data should display only check_groupReports=something, otherwise if both combobox have selectedindex or text, then displayed data should display data with both criteria meets

Found my solution, anyways thanks for the reference codes
Sub searchReports()
     Dim query1 As String = "select * from tblchecklist"
     query1 &= " where check_date between @date1 and @date2"
     query1 &= " and check_corporate LIKE @check_corporate"
     query1 &= " and check_group LIKE @check_group"

     Try
         dgv_reports.Rows.Clear()
         conn.Open()
         Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query1, conn)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("date1", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom.Value
         cmd.Parameters.Add("date2", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTo.Value
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@check_corporate", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 155).Value = "%" & combo_corpReports.Text & "%"
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@check_group", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 155).Value = "%" & combo_groupReports.Text & "%"

         dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
         While dr.Read
             dgv_reports.Rows.Add(dr.Item("ID"), dr.Item("check_corporate"), dr.Item("check_date"), dr.Item("check_num"), dr.Item("check_name"), dr.Item("check_memo"), dr.Item("check_amount"), dr.Item("check_group"), dr.Item("date_deposit"), dr.Item("date_release"), dr.Item("status"))
         End While
         dr.Dispose()
     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
     End Try
     conn.Close()
 End Sub

